# Best algorithm for finding most occurring combinations of values in a dataset

Tags: php, sql, data-science

```
----------------------------------------
   ColumnA  |  ColumnB      | ColumnC  | 
----------------------------------------
      Cat   |     Shirt     |   Pencil | 
      Dog   |     Shirt     |   Eraser | 
      Worm  |     Dress     |   Pen    | 
      Cow   |     Shirt     |   Pen    | 
      Cat   |     Shirt     |   Pen    | 
      Cat   |     Jacket    |   Pen    | 
      Cow   |     Shirt     |   Pen    | 
      Cat   |     Shirt     |   Pen    | 
      Cat   |     Jacket    |   Pen    | 
      Cow   |     Shirt     |   Pen    | 
      Cat   |     Shirt     |   Pen    | 
      Cat   |     Jacket    |   Pen    |
```

With the example data above I am trying to find the most re-occuring combinations which are a pair of 2 or greater.

For example

```
Shirt,Pen 6
Cat,Pen 6    
Cat,Shirt 4
Jacket, Pen 3
Pen,Cow 3
Cat,Shirt,Pen 3
Cat,Jacket,Pen 3
Cow,Shirt,Pen 3
```

I need this for up to 10 columns of data.

`Cat,Shirt` is the same as `Shirt,Cat`.

What is the best algorithm to use? Preferably in SQL but I could also try PHP?

Comment: `10 columns`? Why is `Cow,Shirt,Pen` in example missing? Is `Cat,Shirt` diff. from `Shirt,Cat`? Do you only want to count up to three fields or also up to 10? Or anything else?

Comment: Why not `Cat ,  Pen, 6`  in your example result ? I'm just  trying get your logic

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I have updated the question

Comment: `I need this for up to 10 columns of data.` ::There will be 1013 possible combinations of the columns. Maybe you should reconsider your data model?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in SQL by identifying each row and adding an "empty" element.  Note:  this assumes that the values are different in each column -- or at least fungible (it doesn't matter which column one is in).

Let me also assume that each row has a unique id:

```
with t as (
      select id, col
      from data d outer apply
           (values (col1), (col2), (col3), (NULL)) v(col)
     )
select t1.col, t2.col, t3.col, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and (t2.col > t1.col or t2.col is null) join
     t t3
     on t1.id = t3.id and (t3.col > t2.col or (t2.col is null and t3.col is null))
group by t1.col, t2.col, t3.col
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way may be would this

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, count(*) FROM (
    SELECT ColumnA AS c1,  ColumnB AS c2, NULL AS c3 FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ColumnA AS c1,  ColumnC AS c2, NULL AS c3 FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ColumnB AS c1,  ColumnC AS c2, NULL AS c3 FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ColumnA AS c1,  ColumnB AS c2, ColumnC AS c3 FROM your_table
) tt
group by c1, c2, c3
order by count(*) desc
```